# Does the electron energy-deposition profile exhibit a Bragg peak?

Tags: electrons

The energy deposition profile of an electron beam impacting a material has this characteristic shape ($1~\mathrm{MeV}$ beam in solid Cu):*

[image: Approximate profile of 1 MeV beam in copper]

What physics mechanism would refer to the peak energy deposition at ~ $.2~\mathrm{mm}$ in the plot above? I've seen in literature that the Bragg peak of an electron beam is never observed, and I believed this is due to straggling? But I was wondering if this peak is, in effect, a bragg peak?

*Using approximation from https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/e04/PAPERS/THPLT122.PDF

Comment: The [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov)'s publications *The Particle Data Book* is a good starting place for these kinds of questions. You want the chapter on the [passage of radiation through matter (PDF link)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bragg peak occurs just before the end of range because the particle deposit all of its energy near Bragg peak.

Absorption $\rightarrow$ reduction in energy $\rightarrow$ more absorption. Near the Bragg peak this mechanism dominate and almost all energy is deposited in that small volume.

The above energy deposition graph can not be taken as Bragg peak, it shows some peak but that is not Bragg peak because 1. it is broad 2. it do not occur near the end of the range but in 1/3 of the range.

It was suggested that the Bragg peak of electron may occur around [1 keV](http://www.med.harvard.edu/jpnm/physics/nmltd/radprin/sect7/7.1/7_1.3.html) where the electron has almost no energy to deposit.

As you know that electron deposits its energy by multiple scattering from nuclei (electorn-ion interaction), and the energy lost depends on 1. Energy of the electorn and 2. The time spent near the ion. With the loss in energy the velocity of the electron reduces which increases the time spent near the ions (resulting in more energy deposition) but with more and more energy loss the electron will have less energy to deposit, these two contradictory processes make the trade off at some point and you will observe the peak of energy deposition.